# How can I find out the sum of these two particular sets of natural numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

With the function $g : A\times B \to \mathbb N$ defined by $g(a,b)=a+b$, how could I determine the subset $C \subseteq \mathbb N$ that is the image of $g$ if I knew the way $A$ and $B$ are constructed, i.e. $A=\{a : a_n \in \mathbb N \quad \mathrm{and} \quad l(n) \le a_n \le u(n)\}$ (the subscripts of $a_n$ and $b_n$ are just used to relate the elements with their bounds) and $B=\{b : b_n=a_n-c\}$ for any $l(n)$ and $u(n)$ and $ c \in \mathbb Z$?

 
So far I have had some success if the members of $A$ are regularly spaced, i.e. when the $k$th member $a_k=a_1+\left \lfloor \frac {(k-1)(a_L-a_1)}{L-1} \right \rceil$, $L$ being the number of elements in $A$. For that special case I found out $C$ would be all the naturals inside $2a_1-c$ and $2a_n-c$ if $L=1+\frac 23 a_n+\frac {2}{3\sqrt 3}\sin \left (\frac {2\pi a_n}{3} \right)$. 

 
For the general case I have not been able to make much progress. Is there a way to determine $C$ from $l(n)$ and $u(n)$ if we know the cardinality of $A$?

Comment: What are $l(n), u(n), a_n, b_n$?  Are these sequences of real numbers?  You should define these things clearly before asking a question about them.

Comment: $l(n)$ and $u(n)$ are functions on the real numbers, I cannot define them clearly because they are placeholders for any function, hence the "general case" in the second to last sentence. $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the $n$th terms of the set. Though sets have no order, I found the subscript useful to link them to their respective bounds.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ sets of real numbers or natural numbers

Comment: $A$ is natural, $B$ can be integer, $c$ is an integer constant

Comment: I'll edit it so there will be no more confusion

Comment: I made some edits that I thought were appropriate (to the title, post, and tags). You are of course free to edit it further.